# C# DataGridView Dynamic Context Menus

Tags: c#, datagridview, contextmenu

I have a C# DataGridView that shows the timing of up to 5 timers.  Using the DataGridView MouseClick event I am able to create a dynamic Context Menu with the options "Start Timer" and "Stop Timer".  See code below.

The trouble I'm having is linking the dynamic Context Menus to a Method.  For example, when selecting "Start Timer 1" I need it to start the first timer, but "Start Timer 2" needs to start a different one.  I already have a method (non Context Menu related) that starts the relevant timer but I'm not sure how to link the two.

I think I need a Context Menu event somewhere but I'm a bit lost.

Any help would be very helpful.

```
private void dataGridView1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) 
{     
   if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)     
   {         
      ContextMenu m = new ContextMenu();         

      int r = dataGridView1.HitTest(e.X,e.Y).RowIndex;

      m.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("Start Timer " + r.ToString()));         
      m.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("Stop Timer " + r.ToString()));         

      m.Show(dataGridView1, new Point(e.X, e.Y));      
   }
}

private void StartTimer(int t)
{
   ... code starts the t timer ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can handle MenuItem.Click event like this:

```
var item = new MenuItem("Start Timer " + r.ToString();
item.Click += (sender, e) => this.StartTimer(r);
m.MenuItems.Add(item)
```

Or you can use Command and CommandParameters if you want to use MVVM (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752308.aspx)

Comment: Nikolay.  I did try the above code but couldn't get it to work.  I understand the idea behind it, so I have posted an answer myself with a working version.  Although very very crude.

Answer (score 0):

After failing to get the above code working I did some more research and now have a crude work around (see below).

I set the context menu as a ContextMenuStrip and linked an ItemClick Event.  I couldn't find a way to pass the "r" variable to the StartTimer method, so I had to set it up as a global, which I know is not the correct C# way of doing things.  I did try getting the EventHandler to run a custom Method with an int argument but it errors with "Method Name Expected".

As I mentioned my code does work but I would appreciate any more advice.

```
private void dataGridView1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
    {
        int r = dataGridView1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y).RowIndex + 1;

        ContextMenuStrip m = new ContextMenuStrip();

        globals.timer = r;

        m.Items.Add("Start");
        m.Items.Add("Stop");
        m.ItemClicked += new ToolStripItemClickedEventHandler(m_ItemClicked);

        m.Show(dataGridView1, new Point(e.X, e.Y));
    }
}

void m_ItemClicked(object sender, ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.ClickedItem.Text)
    {
        case "Start":
            startTimer(globals.timer);
            break;
        case "Stop":
            stopTimer(globals.timer);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

private void startTimer(int t)
{
    // code here to start timer t
} 

private void stopTimer(int t)
{
    // code here to stop timer t
}

static class globals
{
    public static int timer = 0;
}
```

Comment: The idea behind `Item.Click += (sender, e) => this.StartTimer(r);` is that you use lambda-function instead of method. In lambda-function you can capture local variables like `r` and have access to them then lambda invokes so you don't need global variable. Alternatively you can just save `r` in property Tag of ContextMenuStrip and use it in eventHandler

Comment: Ok thanks again Nikolay.  I've not come across Tags or Lambda before so will do some investigation and give it a go.